# How to properly code a scaled inverse Wishart prior for a MCMCglmm model?

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, multivariate-testing

I am running a multivariate model (4 response variables) with two random effects using `MCMCglmm()`. I am currently using a inverse Wishart prior.

```
###current set up for prior
prior.miw<-list(R=list(V=diag(4), nu=0.002), 
                G=list(G1=list(V=diag(4), 
                nu=0.002,   
                alpha.mu=c(0,0,0,0), 
                alpha.V=diag(4)*1000),
                G2=list(V=diag(4), #need to repeat to deal with second random effect
                nu=0.002,   
                alpha.mu=c(0,0,0,0), 
                alpha.V=diag(4)*1000)))
```

Based on my model, it appears I should really run a scaled inverse Wishart prior (see [page 14 of Lemoine 2019](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/oik.05985)).

[image]

My question: how do I make this into a prior that is suitable for my `MCMCglmm()` model?

*Additionally, if this is NOT the sort of prior I should be running, please feel free to weigh in.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using *parameter-expanded* priors (see the `CourseNotes` vignette for `MCMCglmm`; I will come back and give more detail later if/when I get a chance

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks in advance for your help! Hadfield's course notes have definitely been my go-to, but they are not always as accessible as I wish they were!

Comment: Now voting to migrate to CrossValidated.  Can you say more about why "it appears I should really run a scaled inverse Wishart prior"? (i.e., what makes you think the prior you're illustrating is not OK? The only thing I see potentially wrong with it is the tiny scale parameter) (see my answer).

Comment: PS if you know of any other good links/references for the scaled inverse-Wishart (i.e. via parameter expansion as in MCMCglmm/Gelman & Hill/etc.) **in the multivariate case** I'd love to see them

Comment: @BenBolker I actually haven't found anything. The closest thing is the paper I linked to in my OP.  Based on Lemoine 2019, because the variances were small relative to the means, they suggested using a scaled inverse Wishart prior (page 14). Beyond that, I haven't found anything else that was informative (and nothing that touched on multivariate models).

Comment: One other paper I can link to is this one: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i02. It does have some code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two-part question:

- what priors should I use for a multivariate random effect where the likelihood is concentrated at small values? (I am assuming that this is the reason you are looking for an alternative to the default inverse Wishart priors) [more suitable for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)]
- which of these are available in `MCMCglmm`, and how do I implement them there? [good for Stack Overflow]

The general trick is to decompose the covariance matrix into a multivariate component (the correlation matrix or inverse correlation matrix or something) and a vector of scaling parameters for the standard deviations (or inverse standard deviations); Lemoine suggests U(0,100) for the scaling priors, which I think is bad (why flat? I can't get to the precise page of Gelman and Hill 2007 where they discuss *which* distribution to use for scaling priors ... but I would be a little surprised if they actually recommended a uniform distribution on the variance scale ...)

**update having actually looked at your code (!)**: I think you're doing the right thing, except that `nu=0.002` seems really extreme; see end for that discussion.

This is basically what `MCMCglmm` does, but it uses a different (IMO better) choice for the scaling priors. It sounds scary:

> These priors are all from the non-central scaled F-distribution, which implies the prior for the standard deviation is a non-central folded scaled t-distribution (Gelman, 2006).

but it boils down to choosing four parameters, **only two of which you really have to think about**.

- `V`: the prior mean variance (or the prior mean covariance matrix, if you have a multivariate random effect term). According to the course notes, **"without loss of generality V can be set to one"** (or in the case of a multivariate model, to an identity matrix)
- `alpha.mu`: **we almost always want this to be zero** (or as in your example, a vector of zeros); that way the prior for the standard deviation will be a Student t distribution. (There may be a use case for `alpha.mu != 0`, but I've never run across it.)
- `alpha.V`: with `V` set to 1 (or an identity matrix), this is the prior mean of the covariance matrix. A diagonal matrix with a reasonable scale for your problem is a good choice
- `nu`: the shape parameter; as `nu` → ∞ we get a half-Normal prior for the standard deviations, with `nu`=1 we get a Cauchy distribution. Smaller values have fatter tails (less conservative/allowing broader samples, but also giving more danger of weird sampling behaviour in the tails).

For the univariate case Hadfield says the t prior with `V=1` is

```r
2 * dt(sqrt(v)/sqrt(alpha.V), df = nu, 
       ncp = alpha.mu/sqrt(alpha.V))
```

with `v` restricted to be zero.

- If we set `alpha.mu=0` like sensible people the `ncp` (non-centrality parameter) argument is zero;
- the 2 out front doubles the density because we are only looking at the positive half of the distribution ("folded")
- the division by `sqrt(alpha.V)` means we scale the t-distribution by `alpha.V`
- in other words, we would get a sample from the prior SD distribution via `sqrt(alpha.V)*abs(rt(1, nu=nu))`

I wish Hadfield had given an example of parameter expansion in a *multivariate* inverse-Wishart case. Where did you find yours?

---

I think `nu=0.002` is a dangerous choice. Why?

It's tempting to make your priors "as flat as possible", but this has two potentially bad consequences.

- for some cases, such as the inverse-Gamma or Gamma distributions, a small shape parameter will also generate a big spike near zero; this is the case for your residual prior above `R=list(V=diag(4), nu=0.002)`. This is OK if your data are informative (reasonable guess for the residual variance), but will sample badly if they're not.
- for the parameter-expanded case we don't have the spike-at-zero problem (the half-Normal, half-t, and half-Cauchy are flat at zero), but by making the tail so fat, you are potentially allowing the estimator to sample truly ridiculous (and computationally problematic) values. (Again, not a problem if your data are highly informative.) Consider that a t distribution with `nu=1` corresponds to a Cauchy distribution, whose tails are so fat that **its mean is infinite**, then imagine making the shape parameter 500 times smaller (`nu=0.002`) ...

Comment: I originally was using `V=diag(4)` because my model would not run unless the number (here 4) matched the number of response variables. Is `V=1` different in that it is for a univariate model and thus, in my case I'd go with `V=diag(1)` (what I think is an identity matrix)?

Comment: In terms of where I found my code - I just fiddled with bits of code Hadfield included in the course notes until it looked semi-reasonable and ran without throwing me errors. However, I haven't found any places that verify my code is correct. In terms of the formula you include above, is this for the univariate parameter expanded prior? (I have more questions, but I'll start with these.)